# RethinkDB - How to stream data to the browser

Tags: nosql, real-time, rethinkdb

## Context

Greetings,

One day I randomly found RethinkDB and I was really fascinated by the whole real-time changes thing. In order to learn how to use this tool I quickly spinned up a container running RethinkDB and i started making a small project. I wanted to make something very simple therefore i thought about creating a service in which speakers can create room and the audience can ask questions. Other users can upvote questions in order to let the speaker know which one are the best. Obviously this project has a lot of realtime needs that i believe are best satisfied by using RethinkDB.

## Design

I wanted to use a vary specific set of tools for this. The backend would be made in Laravel Lumen, the frontend in Vue.JS and the database of course would be RethinkDB.

## The problem

RethinkDB as it seems is not designed to be exposed to the end user directly despite the fact that no security concern exists.

Assuming that the user only needs to see the questions and the upvoted in real time, no write permissions are needed and if a user changed the room ID nothing bad will happen since the rooms are all publicly accessible.

Therefore something is needed in order to await data updates and push it through a socket to the client (socket.io for example or pusher).

Given the fact that the backend is written in PHP i cannot tell Lumen to stay awake and wait for data updates. From what i have seen from the online tutorials a secondary system should be used that should listen for changes and then push them. (lets say a node.js service for example)

This is understandable however i strongly believe that this way of transferring the data to the user is inefficient and it defeats the purpose of RethinkDB.

If I have to send the action from the client's computer (user asks a question), save it to the database, have a script that listens for changes, then push the changes to socket.io and finally have the client (vue.js) act when a new event arrives, what is the point of having a real-time database in the first place?

I could avoid all this headache simply by having the Lumen app push the event directly to socket.io and user any other database system instead.

I really cant understand the point of all this. I am not experienced with no-sql databases by any means but i really want to experiment with them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This is understandable however i strongly believe that this way of transferring the data to the user is inefficient and it defeats the purpose of RethinkDB.

RethinkDB has no built in mechanism to transfer data to end-users. It has no access control (in the conventional sense) as well. The common way, like you said, is to spin up one / multiple node instance(s) running socket.io. On each instance you can listen on your RethinkDB change streams and use socket.io's broadcast functionality. This would be a common way, but as RethinkDB's streams are pretty optimized, you could also open a change stream for every incoming socket.io connection.

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaank you so much, you saved my day bro (*RethinkDB has no built in mechanism to transfer data to end-users*), How stupid I am, that should be obvious from the beginning.

Comment: Yeah, this caught me off guard as well. Have a look at PouchDB / CouchDB (optionally with RxDB).